# I am not able to run javafx program even after installing javafx in eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I am not able to run javafx program even after installing javafx in eclipse.[screeenshot of error I am getting after running javafx program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3pmx.png)

Comment: The class DisplayText is missing. Furthermore all javafx imports are missing. "publicstaticvoid" has to have spaces between the words.

Comment: just seeing that this is a repost of your earlier question - DONT DONT DONT! Instead edit the first to make it answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not installing javafx correctly you can see the video below he can help you
This video can help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7OM-cMYWbQ&ab_channel=BroCode?
And this is the code to test

```
public class HelloWorld extends Application {
//---------------------------------------------
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
primaryStage.setTitle("My First JavaFX App");
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
Button btnHello = new Button("Hello World");
root.setCenter(btnHello);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 100);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}
//---------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}
}
'''
```